# Scala for/yield with multiple optional calls based on credentials

Tags: scala, lagom

I need to get an entire case class, built with 3 other case classes, back in one call. However, depending on a users credentials they may or may not have access to certain parts of that case class.

Below is how I'm currently doing it.(and it works) It's making the call but clearing out the unauthorized case classes afterwards. I would ideally like to stop the call (due to low bandwidth) if they don't have the proper credentials and return None.

The persistent entity service call is expecting an Option[PersonOne] and Option[PersonTwo] so the .ask must return that or it says it's returning an object and won't compile.

```
override def getPerson(id: UUID, credOne: Option[Boolean], credTwo: Option[Boolean]) = ServerServiceCall { _ =>
for {
  g <- registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonGeneral)
  h <- registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonOne) //if (credOne) **this 'if' does not work**

  s <- registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonTwo)
} yield {
  val x: Option[PersonOne] = if (credOne == Some(true)) h else None
  val y: Option[PersonTwo] = if (credTwo == Some(true)) s else None
  CompletePerson(g.get, x, y)

  //TODO catch if no employee is returned
  //throw NotFound (s"Person not Found with $id");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of your function that will only call `ask` if the appropriate credential value is `Some(true)`:

```
override def getPerson(id: UUID, credOne: Option[Boolean], credTwo: Option[Boolean]) = ServerServiceCall { _ =>
  CompletePerson(
    registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonGeneral).get,
    credOne.filter(_ == true).flatMap(_ => registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonOne)),
    credTwo.filter(_ == true).flatMap(_ => registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonTwo))
  )
}
```

The key part is this:

```
credX.filter(_ == true).flatMap(...)
```

- If `credX` is `None` this will return `None`
- If `credX` contains `false` it will return `None`
- If `credX` is `Some(true)` then `flatMap` will call the `ask` function
- If `ask` returns `None` then the expression will return `None`, otherwise it will return `Some[PersonX]`

I am a bit unclear on some of the data types, but I think this should give you some idea of how to approach this code. (For example, that bare `.get` look dangerous as it could throw an exception)

#### Edit after comments

I fixed an issue with the `filter(_)`, it should be `filter(_ == true)`.

It looks like `ask` actually returns `Option[Option[T]]`, in which case this might be closer to what is needed.

```
def getPerson(id: UUID, credOne: Option[Boolean], credTwo: Option[Boolean]) = ServerServiceCall { _ =>
  for {
    g <- registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonGeneral)
    gen <- g
  } yield {
    val p1 = credOne.filter(_ == true).flatMap(_ => registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonOne))).flatten
    val p2 = credTwo.filter(_ == true).flatMap(_ => registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonTwo))).flatten

    CompletePerson(gen, p1, p2)
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought this one was going to work! Made a lot of sense. Here are the Errors, it's not sure of the return values:
  ------Type Mismatch, expected RequestHeader,NotInferredRequests => Future[(same)], actual NotUsed => CompletePerson

-------expected; NotInferedRequest => Future[same], actual NotUsed => CompletePerson  

---------Option[PersonGeneral], actual Future[GetPersonGeneral.Reply.type]

Comment: I have fixed an issue with the `filter` and added another version which assumes that `ask` returns `Option[Option[T]` because that is how I can make sense of the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but are you concerned that if

```
registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonGeneral)
```

returns `None` that you'll keep making expensive `.ask` calls? Cos that won't happen, as we can see from this

```
def giveMeSome = {println("giving you Some"); Some(1)}
def giveMeNone = {println("giving you None"); None}
def giveMeSomeMore = {println("giving you Some more"); Some(2)}

val ans = for {
  a <- giveMeSome
  f <- giveMeNone
  q <- giveMeSomeMore
} yield (a, f, q)

println(ans)
```

which prints

```
giving you Some
giving you None
None
```

We can also see that in this case, you'll get `None` back. I can't tell if you want a `None` or an error thrown. If you want an error, you can just wrap what's above

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I've had the methods broken out like that. But no matter where I put the "if" statement, in whatever form. It will throw a Future type mismatch error. So hopefully to clarify, if general doesn't pull back info (then all three won't) then i'll return "Person not found". However the other two should or should not be called based on credentials and may or may not pull back info, so a case class or a None depending on how much info is in the system about a particular person.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question completely, but based on my understanding you want to first check if credOne == Some(true) && credTwo == Some(true) then proceed further else return None

```
override def getPerson(id: UUID, credOne: Option[Boolean], credTwo: Option[Boolean]) 
  =
   for {
       cone <- credOne
       ctwo <- credTwo
       if cone
       if ctwo
   } yield {
   ServerServiceCall { _ =>
     for {
         g <- registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonGeneral)
         h <- registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonOne)
         s <- registry.refFor[PersonEntity](id.toString()).ask(GetPersonTwo)
         if g.isDefined
         } yield {
           CompletePerson(g.get, h, s)
          }
       }
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. It's not first check to see if both are true. General will pull back info or it won't, but it needs to be called regardless. One and Two should be called based on whether or not they have credentials for it. And if they have credentials then can pull back one or both. When it's pulled back it may have values or it may be None depending on where HR is in the process of filling out this person.